# Defining custom style rules for unordered/ordered lists

Tags: css, ckeditor, html-lists

I have a use case in CKEditor where a user may need to insert a Unordered or Ordered list, but due to the site's brand guidelines, we need to provide the option to color the bullets or numbers. I have looked at the List Style plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/liststyle) but it does not provide that featureset nor does it provide any insight on how to add that kind of setting in the plugin itself. What are my best options to add this functionality to CKEditor?

Comment: Add custom css to do that on all the OL & UL or create a class which users can add by going in the source mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin or modify an existing plugin to color the list items with this code:

```
  var colorStyleLi = {
    element: 'li',
    styles: { 'color': '#(color)' }
  };

  var sel = editor.getSelection();
  var ranges = sel.getRanges();
  var st = new CKEDITOR.style(colorStyleLi, { color: color } );
  for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; ++i) {
     var walker = new CKEDITOR.dom.walker(ranges[i]),
        node;
     while((node = walker.next())) {
        if(node.type==CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT) {
           st.applyToObject(node, editor);
        } else {
           var p = node.getParent();
           st.applyToObject(p, editor);
        }
     }
  }
```